# How to correctly display a list of entities containing string fields with HTML formatting

Tags: xdocreport

I have a list of entities. They, in turn, contain String fields which can contain html formatting (they are filled from rich text areas), including embedded images. The list of entities should be displayed in a generated report as a table, showing the values in these fields.

Sample entity code:

```
public class Entity {
    String htmlFormatted;
    String anotherHtmlFormatted;
    List<String> listOfHtmlFormattedStrings;
    // ...
}
```

I load report template, add the list of entities to it, and process it:

```
IXDocReport report = ...
// metadata
metadata.addFieldAsTextStyling("entity.anotherHtmlFormatted", SyntaxKind.Html);

List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
// add a list
entities.add(...);
context.put("entities", entities);

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("..."));
report.process(context, out);
```

Template docx file contains `#foreach($entity in $entities)` directive around a table. In the table, cells are populated using e.g. `$entity.anotherHtmlFormatted`, and list fields are rendered within their own *foreach* within cells.

I use `metadata.addFieldAsTextStyling("entity.htmlFormatted", SyntaxKind.Html)`, but, for example, embedded images in this are not displayed. Also, lists have some weird empty symbols in front bullets.

What do I do to get correct display of the fields? And how to display list fields correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just about embedded images, XDocReport 1.0.4, doesn't support img HTML tag for HTML Text styling. See [HTML Supported styles](https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/wiki/DocxReportingJavaMainHTMLTextStyling#Supported_styles) to know which HTML tags are supported.

If you have other problem with text styling, please create a [XDocReport issue](https://code.google.com/p/xdocreport/issues/list) by attaching your docx+java main.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've managed to work around by using Docx4J, after XDocReport finishes processing. I XdocReport creates docx file with markers in places where HTML styled content should be, and Docx4J imports HTML code in place of these markers.